# Integral of exponential of exponential of a rational function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> How I can calculate the following integral:
>   $$\int_A^B \frac{1-\exp(-a \exp(-b/x))}{1+\exp(-a \, \exp(-b/x))+c \, \exp(-d/x)} dx$$

Thanks in advance for your help.
Ari

Comment: You should show us what you have tried.

Comment: Do you really hope to find a close form ? (is it an exercice ?)

Comment: It is not an exercise, but I hope that I can find a closed form solution. Even an asymptotic solution in the vicinity of large $b/x$ would be useful.

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).